# Swift: Array - removing elements when condition is met

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing

lets say I have a list of features lasting only a certain amount of time

I periodically loop over an array of features checking if the time is over.
when the condition is met I remove the particular element but I get an index error - because the array length changes and the for loop still goes over the "old" length of the array..

what's the proper way of doing this? (lets say the array is very big, do I need to make a new array, do I need to make a second loop ? ... )

```
struct Feature {
    let name: String
    var remains: Int
}
var features = [Feature(name: "1", remains: 2), Feature(name: "2", remains: 3), Feature(name: "3", remains: 3)]

while true {
for index in 0..<features.count {
    features[index].remains -= 1
    if features[index].remains == 0 {
        features.remove(at: index)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you really need a mutating solution, what about a Date to keep track of when the feature expires? Then you could filter out all expired elements instead.

Comment: good input from all of you! @JoakimDanielson that's an interesting thought. if I would have thousands of features do you think a non-mutating solution would come with some beneficial performance implications?

Comment: Yes I do believe so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this code snippet is really what you need to do (as @Joakim says, there may be other options), you need to make sure that indices remain valid after deleting objects.

One easy way to achieve this is by going through the array backwards, from end to start, by simply adding a `.reversed()`:

```
for index in (0..<features.count).reversed() { ... }
```

That said, if you can move the deletion of all items where `remains == 0` to a later pass, then it is as simple as

`features.removeAll { $0.remains == 0 }`

Comment: Another solution would be `features.map { var feature = $0; feature.remains -= 1; return feature }.filter { $0.remains == 0 }` I also think it would be easier to increase an external variable `var remains: Int` and always get `features.filter { $0.remains > remains }`

Answer (score 0):

If the array is very big, I would say it would be much simpler to keep an external variable and increase it instead of decreasing the value in all the data.

```
var currentLimit: Int = 0

...

curentLimit += 1
features.removeAll { $0.remains < currentLimit }
```